# Filling in List if found for deserialization is not found

Tags: java, file, javafx, deserialization, file-handling

I have a javafx application with a Controller which has a `List` of `Book` objects. I've managed to serialize this list when I want, and deserialize it when my application closes or updates the List. However, I would like to make it so that if the file is not found (aka, the first time the application is run), the List would instead be filled with predetermined objects. How may I achieve this?

Here's the method I use to deserialize:

```
public  void DeserializeDatabase() throws FileNotFoundException { //the name database is just required for the exercise
        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
                new FileInputStream("members.dat"))) {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    User user = (User)ois.readObject();
                    users.add(user);
                } catch (EOFException eofe){
                    break;
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Here's the constructor for the Controller:

```
 public Database() throws FileNotFoundException {
        this.users = new ArrayList<>();
        //users.add(new User(1, "user1", "lastName1", LocalDate.of(2020, 4, 29), "0000"));
        //users.add(new User(2, "user2", "lastName2", LocalDate.of(1992, 4, 17), "0000"));
        DeserializeDatabase();
    }
```

(the commented out objects are the ones I would like to add if the file is not found)

Any help is greatly appreciated, please do tell if more information is required

Comment: Can't you just catch the `FileNotFoundException` exception, and then execute the commented lines only when you do so?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am rather new to java, the code for file handling was taken from some slides. How may I catch the exception? I have attempted a `try {DeserializeDatabase()}` ,with the catch being adding those two objects but I probably did it wrong and it did not quite work.

Comment: `java.util.prefs.Preferences` is ideal for this.

Comment: For an example of `Preferences` use in a Makery tutorial for doing something like this, see the [makery tutorial](https://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-tutorial/part5/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User @CryptoFool was right. I ended up catching the `FileNotFoundException` and added the default objects there. The method ended up as:

```
public  void DeserializeDatabase() {
    try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("members.dat"))) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                User user = (User) ois.readObject();
                users.add(user);
            } catch (EOFException eofe) {
                break;
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException fnf) {
        users.add(new User(//user stuff);
        users.add(new User(//user stuff);
    }
}
```